# Screenshot of InAppBrowser?

Tags: cordova, screenshot, inappbrowser, webpage-screenshot

I want to create a screenshot of the InAppBrowser with PhoneGap.
I've searched a lot, but I found nothing. Is this even possible?

My targets are: iOS and Android

Answer (score 2):

The [cordova screenshot plugin](https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot) helps you, if you want to take a screenshot of the main window. The screenshot will be saved in the app storage, so you don't need access to the device gallery.

But if you use the [InAppBrowser Plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html) to open a new window like this

```
var ref = window.open('http://www.yoursubwindow.com', '_blank')
```

then you won't be able to take a screenshot of `ref`.

*Reason*: `ref` is not a plain Javascript browser window but an `InAppBrowser` object with limited access to the browser window. In particular, you won't have access to the Javascript `window.navigator` object, which is used in the cordova screenshot plugin to take a screenshot.

So if you take a screenshot with `window.navigator.screenshot.save(...)`, it will always take a screenshot of the underlying window (main window), but never of `ref`.

`ref.navigator.screenshot.save(...)` will result in a javascript error, since `ref.navigator` is not defined.

I am working on that problem myself now but I haven't figured out a solution yet. So if you find one, let me know!

Comment: Do you try this in the developer app or you deployed into your device?

Comment: I deployed it on an iPad Air.

Comment: The plugin works for iOS (and any other OS for that matter) as long as you want to take a screenshot from the main window. But it doesn't work to take a screenshot of the InAppBrowser window.

Comment: Did you find something for this?

Answer (score 0):

This PhoneGap plugin should help you:

`cordova-screenshot`

https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot

Usage:

```
navigator.screenshot.save(function(error,res){
  if(error){
  console.error(error);
  }else{
    console.log('ok',res.filePath);
  }
});
```

Comment: How does that work in iOS? Where the app don't have access to photos?

Answer (score 0):

As its written in comments cordova-screenshot plugin is not working correctly with inAppBrowser. But still you can implement screenshot in inAppBrowser plugin code. There are several solution already on stackoverflow. I used the following code for Android (edited InAppBrowser.java code):

//In my code a postmessage triggers the functionality so on some postmessage it returns the object as postMessage to cordova where I'm catching and using the data:image

```
public void screenShare(JSONObject obj) {
       final WebView childView = inAppWebView;
       Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(childView.getWidth(), childView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
       Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
       childView.draw(canvas);
       int quality = 100;
       ByteArrayOutputStream jpeg_data = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       if (bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, jpeg_data)) {
           byte[] code = jpeg_data.toByteArray();
           byte[] output = Base64.encode(code, Base64.NO_WRAP);
           String js_out = new String(output);
           js_out = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + js_out;
           try {
               obj.put("screen", js_out);
               LOG.d(LOG_TAG, "screen result sending" );
               sendUpdate(obj, true);
           }catch (JSONException ex) {
               LOG.e(LOG_TAG, "data screenshare object passed to postMessage has caused a JSON error.");
           }
       } else{
           LOG.d(LOG_TAG, "No screen result " );
       }
   }
```

For iOs I edited CDVUIInappBrowser.m 
I'm using postmessage aswell for functionality trigger and I used the following code:

//Calling of the functionality:

```
NSString *imageStr = [self getScreenshot5];
```

//returns data:image

```
- (NSString *)getScreenshot5
{
    UIImage *viewImage = [self captureScreen:self.inAppBrowserViewController.view];
    // For error information
        NSError *error;
        NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
        NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/IMG_FOLDER"];

        if (![fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder

        //Get the current date and time and set as image name
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss";
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
        NSString *gmtTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
        NSLog(@"The Current Time is :%@", gmtTime);

        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(viewImage, 0.9); // _postImage is your image file and you can use JPEG representation or PNG as your wish
        int imgSize = imageData.length;
        NSLog(@"SIZE OF IMAGE: %.2f Kb", (float)imgSize/1024);

        NSString *imgfileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", gmtTime, @".jpg"];
         NSString *imgfilePath= [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imgfileName];
        return imgfilePath;
}

-(UIImage*)captureScreen:(UIView*) viewToCapture
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewToCapture.bounds.size);
    [viewToCapture.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return viewImage;
}
```

Comment: Do you care to show how you trigger the screenShare java method from the Javascript using postmessage?